# How do you reference a textfield and enter it into a mutable array

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

So I need to have whatever was entered in a textfield saved into a nsmutablearray (this has to happen multiple times! and each time it must be saved as another object). but whatever I'm doing clearly isn't working, for it says that "text" isn't in the structure or union.  Heres my code. thanks for any input!

problems are in the enteredClassText method.

```
#import "EnteringCoursesViewController.h"
#import "SelectRotationController.h"


@implementation EnteringCoursesViewController

@synthesize classField;
@synthesize indicatedClass;
@synthesize labelClassTitle;
@synthesize selectRotationController;
@synthesize classesEnteredTable;

- (IBAction)chooseType {
    UIActionSheet *typeSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Class types"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Core Class", @"Elective", nil];
    [typeSheet showInView:self.view];
    [typeSheet release];
}   

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 6 times per rotation", indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 3 times per rotation", indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    } 

}

- (IBAction)chooseFirstMeeting:(id)sender {     
    SelectRotationController *selectView = [[SelectRotationController alloc] 
                                                 initWithNibName:@"SelectRotationController"
                                                 bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [selectView.navigationItem setTitle:@"First Period Day Choose"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectRotationController animated:YES];
    self.selectRotationController = selectView; 
    [selectView release];
}

- (IBAction)enteredClassText:(id)sender {
        NSMutableArray *classesEntered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sender.text];
        [classesEntered = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [classesEntered release];   

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [classField release];
    [labelClassTitle release];
    [indicatedClass release];
    [selectRotationController release];
    [classesEnteredTable release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

When your button is pressed you should take what was entered, convert it to a string, and save that string to the array. This should be fairly easy to accomplish. Here is some sample code:

```
@interface

NSMutableArray *theArray;
```

---

```
@implementation

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

NSString *theStringToAdd = textField.text;
[theArray addObject:theStringToAdd];

}
```

Beware that I haven't tested this code!

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `[theArray addObject:theStringToAdd];` ?

Comment: dont forget [textField resignFirstResponder] if you want to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
- (IBAction)enteredClassText:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *classesEntered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sender.text];
    [classesEntered = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [classesEntered release];
```

}

To fix this, try referencing it as

```
[(UITextField*)sender text]
```

So you final code would look like this:

```
 - (IBAction)enteredClassText:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *classesEntered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[(UITextField*)sender text]];
    [classesEntered = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [classesEntered release];
```

}

This tells the program to assume that sender will be a UITextView.